# php session does not save all variables and saves variables with different "name" as assigned

Tags: php, session

I am having an issue with sessions in php.

I have one page called "blog.php" which I start with session_start() at the beginning and then I have a form to input the username and password:

```
<?php
session_start();?>

<p align="center">To be able to make a post, please sign in.</p>

<table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="logincheck.php">
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><strong>Member Login </strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="78">Username</td>
<td width="6">:</td>
<td width="294"><input name="user" type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="pass" type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>
```

And then I have another page called "logincheck.php" where I also begin with session_start() and then I am trying to access and use the input the user made:

```
<?php
session_start();
$username = $_POST['user'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];
?>
```

Now with this I am getting 2 notices of Undefined index; one for "user" and the other for "pass".

Then I used var_dump($_POST); to see what (if any) is passed through and as a result I got this:

```
array (size=1)
  'u' => string '�T�e�s�t� �U�s�e�r�' (length=19)
```

So somehow the variables I want to save are not saved properly as first of all I have 2 inputs from the user, so the array size should be 2; and second I am saving the string "Test User" under the variable "user" and not "u" as sthe var_dumb($_POST) is showing me.
I am out of ideas, because with another project it all worked fine.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

---

**EDIT**: Nothing wrong with the code, was my mistake as I did not change the root directory on my server.

But mistake occurs again, when I am involving a third page by changing logincheck.php to:

```
<?php
session_start();
$username = $_POST['user'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];
header("location:blog_reg.php"); //<--new
?>
```

The blog_reg.php has the following code:

```
<?php
session_start();
echo "<p align='center'>Hello ", $_SESSION['user'], "!";
?>
```

Using `var_dump($_POST);` shows on blog_reg.php:

```
array (size=0)
  empty
```

and gives me the "undefined index: user" notice.

Any ideas?

---

**EDIT 2**:

Ok. Something seems to be wrong with this session thing as I just tried a very simple code:
1.php:

```
<?php    
session_start();
$_SESSION['test'] = "hi";
header("location:2.php");
?>
```

2.php:

```
<?php    
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['test'];    
?>
```

And the error: `Notice: Undefined index: test in C:\wamp\www\test\2.php on line 4`

---

**[*SOLVED*]** - Finally after hours of testing and checking [James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2632129/james/) and I found a solution.
In php.ini we had to change session.use_cookies to the value 1.

Again a big big thanks to [James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2632129/james/) who bared with me patiently over the last couple of hours.

Comment: I see 2 possible mistakes. You are missing a form, or it is above the session_start(). The session_start() needs to be executed BEFORE anything is echoed.

Comment: @Anton: In both pages the session_start() is the first line in the php files. And as you can see, the form is there. I posted the code above..

Comment: @Anton there would be an error to signify this issue "Headers already sent" etc

Comment: @Sarah see my answer edit

Comment: Please never put "SOLVED" or similar within the title.  The green checkmark next to the answer is enough.  Edited. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT - issue resolved:

Just for clarity, after discussing in chat, it turns out `session.use_cookies` was disabled (unknowingly as OP had used sessions beforehand).

OP turned back on in php.ini and problem is resolved!

Anyone else with a similar issue, run `php_info()` in a PHP script and check the SESSION section to see if there are any issues there.
Such as `session.use_cookies off off` (unless you use session via GET, in which case these do not need to be on, but obviously take care for security if session data is in the URL!)

---

This looks like an encoding issue.

I just ran your code (copy/paste) and it works perfectly fine.

Set your code editor to use *UTF-8 without bom* and then save both files (so they are showing as saved as utf-8), then try running the script again (refresh the page, possibly need to clear out your browser cache, depending on your config).

Test code for logincheck.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$username = $_POST['user'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];

echo $username."<br>".$password;
echo "<br><br>";
var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

### EDIT

In response to your question edit, your `blog_reg.php` is not able to use the session because you do not set one. You are only setting variables who's scope are only within that page or included pages, and as you do a `header(Location)` the variables are reset.

Try this in your logincheck.php:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['user']; //<-- Variable changed to session
//$password = $_POST['pass']; DO NOT make a session with this
header("location:blog_reg.php");
```

Then in your `blog_reg.php` it can make use of the new  `$_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['user'];`

DO NOT store passwords in sessions as they are available to the end user and can be easily obtained from a third party.

### 2ND EDIT

Using `var_dump($_POST)` on your blog_reg.php *will* show zero data, as you do not POST any data to it.
You POST the data from blog.php to logincheck.php, then in logincheck.php you convert the POSTed data into a session, then redirect to the blog-reg.php, where you use the SESSION, not POST.

You do not POST from logincheck.php to blog-reg.php, and so blog-reg.php has not POST data and so `var_dump($_POST)``will show zero data.

Have a read about the differences between POST and SESSION, and while there have a look at GET too, so you have a greater understanding of handling data around your PHP application (or in this case single files):

POST
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php
SESSION
http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

GET
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

### CODE YOU NEED:

Sarah, I have tested the below code and it works fine, which means the issue is somewhere else. Perhaps your server config is not working, or you have some other code you are not showing in this question which is interfering with the code working.

It's hard to help when there are so many potential issues at play here.

Make three new files as below, and test them, it is simply your code with the proposed fixes I have made:

**form.php**

```
<?php
session_start();?>

<p align="center">To be able to make a post, please sign in.</p>

<table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="login.php">
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><strong>Member Login </strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="78">Username</td>
<td width="6">:</td>
<td width="294"><input name="user" type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="pass" type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>
```

**login.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['user'];
header("location: result.php");
?>
```

**result.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
echo "<p align='center'>Hello ", $_SESSION['user'], "!";

echo "<br><br>POST DUMP (will be empty)";
var_dump($_POST);

echo "<br><br>SESSION DUMP (will have user name data)";
var_dump($_SESSION);
?>
```

Comment: Code editor already was using UTF-8 without bom, still changed it again. Closed browser completely, but still getting same errors

Comment: Oh my god -.- I found my mistake. I forgot to change the root directory on my server so the file did not acctually parsed through php, hence could not save anything... Thanks to the James anyway :)

Comment: Glad you're sorted, although I did nothing really. Also, it's weird that was your actual issue, because your `var_dump($_POST);` shows "Test User" amongst the question mark characters. Anyway, all good now.

Comment: Hm ok same error again when I'm going to third page -.- 
between the logincheck.php and the third page the session variables are deleted (tho i am not doing it with the code)... with `vqr_dump($_POST);` it is showing empty array.. great -.-

Comment: Is the issue fixed in the previous file (logincheck.php)?

Comment: yes and then i am using `header("location:blog_reg.php")` to go to third page and session variables are deleted
so basically they are getting saved from page one to page two and then they vanish

Comment: is `session_start()` on third page? Might be worth editing your question and posting more of your code.

Comment: Response to your edit: still getting the same error and `var_dump($_POST)` shows empty array..

Comment: Ok :) thx but even when I am using `var_dump($_SESSION)` it shows an empty array after I copy/pasted the three files from here...
grr -.- getting frustrated specially last week i was working on a different project and there everything works fine with sessions

Comment: @Sarah see my new edit "Code you need". There is something else at play here which is stopping the code from working. I have tested in in my system and is fine. Do as per my edit, make those three new files named as I have given, copy and paste the code for each file into each file, and run the `form.php`. If it doesn't work, then you have an issue at your end with your setup, not the PHP code.

Comment: I really apprechiate all your efforts. I copied and pated those three codes and I am not getting an error anymore but the result.php site does not show the user either..

`SESSION DUMP (will have user name data)`
`array (size=1)`
  `'user' => null`

Comment: @Sarah please put this following code in an empty file and tell me what is says on screen from running the file: <?php session_status();

Comment: empty file with `<?php session_status();?>` shows an empty page

Comment: Ah my bad, really sorry, you need to echo that function `<?php echo session_status();?>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64133/discussion-between-sarah-and-james).